# Get all Sakai users of a specific Type

Tags: sakai

I want to get all users with type Students or Professor, for example. The `searchUsers(String criteria, int first, int last)` method of the `UserDirectoryService` only matches against 'id or email, first or last name'.

Is there a way I can get a User or List of Users with other criteria?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. If you file a [Jira](http://jira.sakaiproject.org) then we can implement it.

Of course you could get all users via UserDirectorySergice.getUsers(), then iterate over each and check the type, but that could potentially be very expensive, depending on the number of users and what's been cached.

That method will only get internal users too. External users can only be found via some search criteria.

Bear in mind that users that are externally provisioned (ie LDAP) do not have a fixed type within Sakai like internal users do, as the external source needs to be queried and logic run to determine the type.

Comment: So, there is no workaround with a never-use-it-again bean that I can query the users? I mean, if I have to dive into Sakai code, what are the beans or services should I use? and is there no way I can use it in my `SakaiProxy`? Just now, I'm doing exactly that approach you suggested but it would be just to not get stucked in the project..

Comment: Edit my answer above to add the method call you can use. Do you have internal or external users or both?